# Use Ajax or jQuery to Make Table Element in Rails App Load Separate From Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I have a page with a list of user sites and on it I am making an API call to check the status of something for each site. The problem is that it makes the page take forever to load, so I would like the page to load and then that table element to update after it's done checking using AJAX or jQuery. I'm not great with AJAX or jQuery though and all the Rails/Ajax tutorials I've been reading seem to deal more with forms and data stored within the database. Here's my table element:

**Part of My View**

```
<td>
    <% if HTTParty.get(site.domain + 'api')["status"] == "ok" %>
        OK
    <% else %>
        Error
    <% end %>
</td>
```

**The Controller Action Loading View**

```
def sites_page
    @sites = Site.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    render 'sites_page'
end
```

How can I make this load separately as mentioned above? I know I don't have any attempted code yet, but I really don't know where to start.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just attach AJAX call to the td on window load, it will be evaluated later after page is rendered. AJAX call can be something like this:

```
  $(window).load(function() {
    var target = $(".td-that-will-be-evauated-later")
    url = target.data("url")

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(result){
        target.html(result.body)
      },
      error:  function(xhr, status, error) {
        $(target).html("error");
      }
    })    
  })
```

Url should point to the controller action that will fetch information for particular user, for example:

```
class UsersController < ActionController::Base
  def fetch_info
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @response = @user.fetch_info
    render json: {success: true, body: response.body}
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks cool. I could still use a little clarification though. I added some more code above. Can you update your answer to work with the above or tell me what else you still need to see of my code so I can just copy/paste your code and it would work? Thanks.

Comment: To be honest i don't see a point to give you full copy-paste code. You need to understood how this works on your own, you will need two actions. First for loading view. Second for AJAX request that will be sent after view rendered.

Comment: Sorry, JS just isn't my thing. So is the "url" in the AJAX the API call url? In the url then how would I check for "status" in the JSON. Also, I'm a little unsure what the user controller code does.